# How to authorise send requests using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable when deploying to Render?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an Admin server using Node SDK for Firebase.
When deploying it to [Render](https://render.com/), I am getting an error with the credentials.

[image: Error with the credentials]

Locally ADC uses existing default service account to obtain credentials to authorize requests.
Althought when I am adding `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as Environment variable it doesn't seem to work.

[image: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as Environment variable]

I have tried creating a `.env` and using it in `index.js`. Since, I am new to Node JS, I wasn't able to understand:

- Should the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in `.env` be a JSON?

```
esport GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = {
  "type": "service_account",
  ...
}
```

- How can I use it in my `index.js`? Is it valid to simply put: `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS;` or should I parse it?
- Lastly, do I need use the credentials when intialising app? The example in documentation uses `applicationDefault()`. If yes, what should I replace it with?

```
initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  projectId: 'potion-for-creators',
});
```

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  should be set to a *path* to a JSON file.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! After setting it to the path, it is working fine now. I have added my service JSON to the file structure when deploying but that would be wrong to publish it publicly right?

Comment: Yes, that *must* not be made public - it contains private keys. Will convert my comment into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is expected to contain a *path* to the JSON file containing your credentials file. It shouldn't contain the JSON itself.

The JSON file should not be made public - it contains private keys for your GCP project.